# Trouble with user defined variables

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project for my SQL class and we are doing a project based off the board game Monopoly. I have to use a "User-defined Variable" to show the places on the board that are red. Here are the contents of my table `street_by_color_v`:

```
color_name  site_label       order_site

purple      Mediterranean Avenue    2
purple      Baltic Avenue   4
light blue  Oriental Avenue 7
light blue  Vermont Avenue  9
light blue  Connecticut Avenue  10
violet      St. Charles Place   12
violet      States Avenue   14
violet      Virginia Avenue 15
orange      St. James Place 17
orange      Tennessee Avenue    19
orange      New York Avenue 20
red         Kentucky Avenue 22
red         Indiana Avenue  24
red         Illinois Avenue 25
yellow      Atlantic Avenue 27
yellow      Ventor Avenue   28
yellow      Marvin Gardens  30
green       Pacific Avenue  32
green       North Carolina Avenue   33
green       Pennsylvania Avenue 35
royal blue  Park Place  38
royal blue  Boardwalk   40
```

Here is my code:

```
SET @s_color:='red';
```

When I execute, I run the code:

```
SELECT site_label FROM street_by_color_v
WHERE color_name=@s_color;
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: An error message would be appreciated. 'It doesn't work' isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT site_label FROM street_by_color_v
WHERE color_name='@s_color';

#example
SELECT site_label FROM street_by_color_v
WHERE color_name='royal blue';

SELECT site_label FROM street_by_color_v
WHERE color_name='orange';
```

Thank you .. :)

Comment: Now all of a sudden what I tried to execute before works. I tried the examples of what you gave me and they worked as well. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Why is `'@s_color'` a quoted string?